# OpenJDK Runtime Environment vs Java2 Runtime Environment

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

Is there any difference between "OpenJDK Runtime Environment" and "Java2 Runtime Environment"? I've been asked to make sure Java2 Runtime Environment is available. But when I run `$ java -version` I see:

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.12) (7u25-2.3.12-4ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

I am also asked to arrange Any machine and operating system capable of running java. For this, I also installed Tomcat7 on Mint/Ubuntu machine. Am I done with requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you are done with your requirements..
it is correct only.

OpenJDK (Open Java Development Kit) is a free and open source implementation of the Java programming language. It is the result of an effort Sun Microsystems began in 2006. The implementation is licensed under the GNU General Public License (GPL) with a linking exception.

Java Runtime Environment, is also referred to as the Java Runtime, Runtime Environment

Answer (score 0):

While Oracle's JDK/ JRE is based on OpenJDK, there are some libraries and tools which are different.